# Traveling with a residence card

Tags: visas, france, schengen-visas, air-france

I have a French scientific residence card which will expire in 31 January 2019.

I want to travel France for one week before the expiry date. I am wondering if it is possible to reserve a ticket? will the airport allow me to travel? If yes, so when should I choose the departure date? and if no, so why?

I have heard that I can travel only if my residence card expires in 6 months. Is this true?

Please any help will be very appreciated.

(from comment): I'm not in France right now. I'm thinking of visiting France between the 16th and 25th of January.

Comment: It isn't clear from your question - are you currently in France? Where do you wish to travel? What is your nationality? Generally with a scientifique TDS you can exit and re-enter France or the Schengen area as long as it's valid. I've never heard of the 6 month rule before.

Comment: Salut! merci pour votre réponse. Non je ne suis pas en France maintenant. Je pense à visiter la France entre 16 et 25 Janvier. Oui c'est quand même bizarre pour moi le truc de 6 mois. Du coup j'ai une carte de séjour scientifique Française.

Comment: Ahhh d'accord. Je ne suis pas sûr dans ce cas. Je pense que vous pouvez être absent de la France pendant 6 mois ou un an sans perdre de sa validité, mais cela dépend si votre départ a été enregistré (par exemple, dans un aéroport quittant la zone Schengen). C'est donc avec risque. Si vous avez un passeport sans visa, vous devriez pouvoir vous passer sans TDS. Sinon je ne sais pas. Désolé.

Comment: Where did you hear "that I can travel only if my residence card expires in 6 months"?  Many countries have a six-month rule for *passports* for *visitors.*  The Schengen area has a *three-month* rule (from the intended end of the visit) for passports for visitors.  These rules apply to *visitors,* not to people with residence permits.  It sounds like you're no longer using your scientific residence permit to reside in France, which may have its own implications, but ignoring that issue it is certainly allowed to enter France with that permit up to the date on which it expires.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique en tout cas merci beaucoup pour votre temps! Je vais me renseigner demain à l'ambassade pour plus d'informations. Bzx

Comment: Si cela veut dire quelque chose: j'ai quitté la France pendant 3 mois pour le travail et ce n'était pas un problème pour rentrer. Je serais surpris que le système fonctionne aussi vite que 6 mois! Bonne chance bzx

Comment: @lafemmecosmique Oui en fait j'ai appelé aujourd'hui l'ambassade de France. Bah du coup je peux rentrer la France même si avant 1 jour de l'expiration de la carte de séjour! Alors aucun problème pour rentrer la France:) Merci et bonne année 2019!

Answer (score 4):

> I have heard that I can travel only if my residence card expires in 6 months. Is this true?

No, it is not true.

The [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20190611) (Articles 6 and 8) stipulates only that a **residence permit** must be valid and that this must be checked.

It does not state that it **must** be valid for a specific time on the date of entry.

---

> Article 6
>   **Entry conditions for third-country nationals**
>   ...
>   1 (b) they are in possession of a valid visa, if required pursuant to Council Regulation (EC) No 539/2001 ( 1 ), except where they hold a **valid residence permit** or a valid long-stay visa;
>   ...
>   Article 8
>   **Border checks on persons**
>   ...
>   3. thorough checks as follows:
>   (a) thorough checks on entry shall comprise verification of the conditions governing entry laid down in Article 6(1) and, where applicable, of documents authorising residence and the pursuit of a professional activity. This shall include a detailed examination covering the following aspects:
>   ...
>   (ii) verification that the travel document is accompanied, where applicable, by the requisite visa or **residence permit**;
>   ...

---

**Sources**:

- [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20190611)

  - 2019-06-11 M3

Comment: It might be worthwhile to mention that this is a frequent misunderstanding, and that it probably arises because of minimum *passport* validity requirements.

Comment: @phoog I was considering adding 1(a) of Article 6, but it states 3 months after intended end of visit. Not being so clear cut, I left it out.

Comment: That three month requirement is often added to the 90-day period of admission to generate a.spurious requirement that the passport must be valid for six months at the time admission.  And of course other countries may have a six month validity requirement.  It's certainly confusing for the average traveler.